# sed: can't read Makefile: No such file or directory

Tags: sed, compiling, configure

I tried to replace a line in a `Makefile` with `sed -i -e 's|$(bindir)\/embossupdate|:|' Makefile`, but I got `sed: can't read Makefile: No such file or directory`

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
...
# EMBOSS (ftp://emboss.open-bio.org/pub/EMBOSS/)
ENV EMBOSS_VER 6.6.0
RUN apt-get install libhpdf-dev libpng12-dev libgd-dev -y
ADD EMBOSS-${EMBOSS_VER}.tar.gz /usr/local/
WORKDIR /usr/local/EMBOSS-${EMBOSS_VER}
RUN sed -i -e 's|$(bindir)\/embossupdate|:|' Makefile        
RUN ./configure  --enable-64 --with-thread  --without-x
RUN make
RUN ldconfig
RUN make install
```

What did I do wrong with the sed command?

Comment: It's not about `sed`, but sounds like you don't have `Makefile` in `EMBOSS-${EMBOSS_VER}`.

Comment: I think cuonglm is right.  Further, your `sed`-expression won't do what you except, as you forgot to escape `$`, which will match the end-of-line in this expression.

Comment: @AndreasWiese The `$` is an ordinary character unless at the end of the expression (or at the end of a group) in a BRE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Makefile is not created until you've run the `configure` script.  Try placing the `sed` command *after* the invocation of `configure`.

I haven't checked if the `sed` edit is doing what it should or not, but the main issue is probably that the Makefile simply doesn't exist yet at that point in your script.

In general, I would avoid `sed -i` as its semantics is different for GNU and BSD `sed`. It's safer to `sed ... file >tmpfile && mv tmpfile file`.